# How to display logs using Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, redis, notifications

I have a web application running using Django. I want to display the backend activities as logs on the frontend. How do I post such notifications on frontend using Django? Any help is appreciated. The Django version I'm using is 1.6.11.

Comment: First, Update the Django version, its too old one.

Comment: True, your version is really old, maybe is time to looks some more updated

Comment: Which is the suggested version of Django using Python 2.7.x for production?

Answer (score 0):

All information about your accsing the url is holded at request

*view.py*

```
def someView(request):
    print(request)
```

You can extract the information and manipulate that you want from request and add it to context to send that as text to your front end.

If you just trying to get some feeback at your frontend i strongly suggest just use django-debug-toolbar, it already bring to you all information about connection, requests, static and all stuffs to your backend while DEBUG IS TRUE, so this is dev tools...

https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

But if you want to build something like that for production you will have to loop more in depth of django to extract all the information and send it to your template